# How to get directories in $PATH as a list or array?

Tags: c, linux, unix

Is there a C function call in linux that helps me get all the files in the directories of $PATH as a list or an array? Or should we parse through the $PATH variable manually to get them?

Comment: All you need to do is split on `;`. `strtok` should be all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
char *colon_delimited_path = getenv("PATH")
```

returns a `:`-delimited list of the directories in PATH.  To translate to an array, you can use `strtok` to split the string.

Comment: [`strtok_r`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strtok.html) would be safer, since `strtok` is not thread-safe.